# power by dashboard with machine learning azure data

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-machine-learning-service

Hi I have a web service which is the result of my machine learning azure training. I would like to set a new datasource in power bi, which calls the web service with the current datetime as a parameter in order to create a report with the result predictions. I cannot find a way to call the api. Is this any? I am thinking another solution of creating a service and execute the api, and insert the result in a table in order to connect to this table. But, I would like to avoid doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used something called Azure Data Factory (ADF). It allows you to schedule a job by defining a pipeline with activities. There are activities for training your model or scoring your predictive ML. The scoring result, I am storing it in Azure DB (it could be another storage) and connected it to Power BI.

Comment: This is a also a great way to do this. I find Data Factory a bit harder to set up then Stream Analytics which is why I made my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way to connect PowerBI from AML directly.

I would recommend that you create a program using Azure Functions
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/

to send the current time to Event Hub
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-hubs/

then, use Stream Analytics to pull that event from Event Hub, and connect your ASA stream to your AML service using Stream Analytics funcitons.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/stream-analytics/
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/machinelearning/2015/12/10/azure-ml-now-available-as-a-function-in-azure-stream-analytics/

In Stream Analytics, you can add PowerBI as an "output". This will create a new dataset in your PowerBI online workspace, that will update in real time as your data generator sends messages into event hub.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-power-bi-dashboard/